# binding textbox to combobox items

Tags: vb.net, combobox, textbox

I have 2 columns in datatable and both are shown in dropdown-list of combobox (multiple-column drop-down list). Now I want to display one column in combobox, and other one in texbox (with databinding). Code works, but 1 problem - I want to have my combobox.selectedIndex -1 when form opens, and textbox empty. Combobox is not an issue, but Texbox can't be cleared of text. Here is my code:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim SQL As String = "SELECT Name,Surname from MyTable"

        Dim dtb As New DataTable()
        dtb.Columns.Add("Name", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        dtb.Columns.Add("Surname", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))

        Using con As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection("Data Source=MyDB;User Id=Lucky;Password=MyPassword;")

            Try

                OraclePovezava.Open()

                Using dad As New OracleDataAdapter(SQL, con)
                    dad.Fill(dtb)

                End Using

                Combobox1.DataSource = dtb
                Combobox1.DisplayMember = "Surname"
                Combobox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
                Combobox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
                con.Close()

            Catch ex As Exception
                'MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Finally
                con.Dispose()
            End Try

            TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", dtb, "Name")
            Combobox1.SelectedIndex = -1

       End Using

    End Sub
```

This code is, as you see, in form's load event. I have tried with Textbox databinding in Combobox.SelectedIndexChanged event with If statement too, but It didn't work.

P.S.: My desired output is that when user selects some item from combobox, both column values are shown in texbox & combobox. Code as you see works that, but Textbox can't be empty like combobox on form's load.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Your TextBox isn't bound to the Name column. It's bound to the Name of your data table. I presume you want the textbox to be populated with the first name of whoever is selected in the combobox?

Comment: Yes, I want that. But what do you mean about Texbox - It is bound to column "Name" of dtb Dataset, Isn't It ? I see displayed as that...

Comment: I just tried your code and thats a genuine surprise to me that it that it binds to the field. Let me amend my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source data table has no record with blank data in it so your textbox is always bound to one of the records with data. I'd implement this using a simple event handler instead of data binding.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
        TextBox1.Text = ""
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = CStr(CType(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, DataRowView)("Name"))
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks FloatingKiwi, that works. Just one problem more here - when I manually delete combobox item... - can I clear textbox.text too, automatically ?...Probably text_changed event of combobox...

Comment: I figured out, I just placed your suggestion in Text_Changed_event. Now everything works, even If I delete text. Is that ok ?

Comment: Yeah, that'll work. You might also need to consider what happens if you enter something in the combo text editor that isn't in the combo drop down.

Comment: I considered that too - It deletes textbox.text, which is fine. Combobox and textbox will be used to save data in my DB, so If user wishes to entry some other name/surname that is not in the list, this enables It. Thanks for help man !!